# Centering components in a Layout

Tags: css, vaadin

I'm trying to center a picture and a label into a Vertical layout so here's the code i wrote:

```
    picture = new Embedded(null,  BrandableResourceHelper.getInstance().newResource("image/icon.png"));
    lab = new Label();
    lab.setWidth(100, UNITS_PERCENTAGE);

    VerticalLayout col = new VerticalLayout();
    col.addComponent(picture);
    col.addComponent(lab);
    col.setWidth(30, UNITS_PERCENTAGE);
    col.setComponentAlignment(picture, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    col.setComponentAlignment(lab, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
```

Here's what i wanna get:

[image]

Here's what i'm getting:

[image]

Comment: Change width of label to null, lab.setWidth(null); and see if that works

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar's suggestion is based on the fact that [by default the labels have a 100% width](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-label.html), so there's nothing left to center. Additionally I prefer using the dedicated `setWidthUndefined()` which has the same effect, but for me is clearer.